# in Shell, How to insert a substring if not found in string

Tags: linux, shell, diffstat

I want changes_summary to always be in format `<x> files changed, <y> insertion(+), <z> deletions(-)` where `<x> <y>` and `<z>` are some numbers, but diffstat misses insertions and/or deletions part if `<y>` and/or `<z>` is zero, I tried to make it print as `<x> files changed 0 insertion(+), 0 deletions(-)` always, is there a better or easy way to do this? I would like to change *$changes_summary* variable so I can use it later part of the script.

```
changes_summary=`diff -ur ./dir1 ./dir2 | diffstat | tail -1`
  if ! echo $changes_summary | grep -q "insertions" && ! echo $changes_summary | grep -q "deletions" ; then
        echo $changes_summary | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " "0 insertion(+)," " " "0 deletions(-)"}'
 elif ! echo $changes_summary | grep -q "insertions" && echo $changes_summary | grep -q "deletions" ; then
       echo $changes_summary | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " "0 insertion(+), "$4 " " $5  }'
elif echo $changes_summary | grep -q "insertions" && ! echo $changes_summary | grep -q "deletions" ; then
       echo $changes_summary | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 "0 deletions(-)" }'
```

fi

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest you can get without some serious `bash` magic or an other language is something like the following.

```
changes_summary=`diff -ur ./dir1 ./dir2 | diffstat -s`
CC=$(echo "$changes_summary" | sed -n 's:\(.*[0-9]\+ .* changed\).*:\1:p')
II=$(echo "$changes_summary" | sed -n 's:.*\([0-9]\+ insertions\?\).*:\1:p')
DD=$(echo "$changes_summary" | sed -n 's:.*\([0-9]\+ deletions\?\).*:\1:p')
echo "${CC}, ${II:-0 insertions}(+), ${DD:-0 deletions}(-)"
```

Sed strips out the message corresponding to each stat. The `-n` suppresses the normal output, `p` prints only if a match is found. If not, then CC, II, DD will be empty, in which case the `${II:-...}` pattern substitutes a default value.

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter:-word}` Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null,
>   the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of
>   parameter is substituted.

Note that keeping the (s) with `s\?` might be an overkill for you.

The other option is that in bash you can check for containment with `[[ $a =~ "b" ]]` and use your original approach. It spares you the greps at least and `"b"` here can also be regex if you drop the quotes.

```
if ! [[ "$changes_summary" =~ "insert" ]]; then
  awk ...
fi
```

You can also find the `=~` in `man bash`.